# Installed kali and ubuntu with usb on d drive, cant reach c drive where windows is op

Tags: ubuntu, usb, kali-linux

I first installed kali linux, -c drive was full so installed kali on d, by using unetbooting- then i got black screen with white cursor then i installed ubuntu with lili, it successfully installed, but there is no windows option in the start,but only kali and ubuntu. I cant access my documents, either. and kali and ubuntu is working fine.

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can list your hard drives and their partitions using

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

once you identified your Windows partition (for example `/dev/sdX1` but that is rather going to differ), you can mount this parition on a given directory with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdX1 /path/to/directory
```

Comment: okay, thanks. but how can i access windows?

Comment: do you know which bootloader you use?

Comment: no. i dont know if i do. computer starts with ubuntu's theme, though.

Comment: find that out. You have to configure your boot loader so that you can choose Windows in its menu. You probably use grub2.This link might be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22629/add-windows-7-to-boot-menu

Comment: gnu grub version 2.02 beta2-9ubuntu1.3, and also i have windwods 10. besides, ubuntu and kali, there are also memory tests.